# SQL Query Comparing datetime overlaps and displaying them

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have directors that pay helpers based on if the helper worked or not when the director did.

Have 2 views as follows:-

**Director**

```
Name    TimeIn                      TimeOut

Bob     2012-07-17 07:00:00.000     2012-07-17 16:00:00.000
Sam     2012-07-17 10:00:00.000     2012-07-17 20:00:00.000
Beatly  2012-07-17 14:00:00.000     2012-07-17 23:00:00.000
Mac     2012-07-17 21:00:00.000     2012-07-18 07:00:00.000
```

**Helper**

```
Name    TimeIn                      TimeOut
Fred    2012-07-17 15:59:00.000     2012-07-18 00:19:00.000
```

Now figuring out who worked during that time isn't the hard part, or at least it isn't the part I am having an issue wrapping my brain around. What is is finding where and what mins and by who this overlap by the min. And group them together by the time used. Because they will all split the hourly pay with the scribe. So ideally the following would be the result.

```
DirName HelperStart                 HelperEnd
Bob     2012-07-17 15:59:00.000     2012-07-17 16:00:00.000
Sam     2012-07-17 15:59:00.000     2012-07-17 16:00:00.000
Beatly  2012-07-17 15:59:00.000     2012-07-17 16:00:00.000
Sam     2012-07-17 16:01:00.000     2012-07-17 20:00:00.000
Beatly  2012-07-17 16:01:00.000     2012-07-17 20:00:00.000
Beatly  2012-07-17 20:01:00.000     2012-07-17 21:00:00.000
Beatly  2012-07-17 21:01:00.000     2012-07-17 23:00:00.000
Mac     2012-07-17 21:01:00.000     2012-07-17 23:00:00.000
Mac     2012-07-17 23:01:00.000     2012-07-18 00:19:00.000
```

Using SQL server 2008. I hope the bare bones simple breakdown is enough. Found enough queries to see if someone conflicts with the time, but no breakdown of the above.

Comment: I don't know that somebody can came upon something, but I can't understand the dates in your result. Maybe less record, more details would be helpful. Even would be nice to post what you tried at the moment. (It helps to see how tables and the existing query built up)

Comment: does a helper 'belong' to a director and how would you know this? without this then i imagine conflicts such as a director has overlapping times with more then one helper.

Comment: You really should be storing and using that end timestamp as an _exclusive_ upper bound.  Think of it as 'the first instant the person was not here', as opposed to 'the last instant the person was here'.

Comment: Whats to not understand on the date. Ill try to explain but this is as simple as I can put it. But its year-month-day hour:min:second:ms as sql server stores datetime stamps.

Comment: helper belongs to no one. They are just at the facility to help. Thus if 3 directors are at the facility at the same time as the helper they will all be paying the helper. I need it grouped by so I can divide it out. So for example if the helper worked 1 hour @ $30 an hour, during the same time period as 3 directors each director would pay 10 an hours. This is where this is all leading.

Comment: So what happens if there are multiple helpers?  Do all directors pay all helpers?  What happens if a helper has been exclusively helping one director - why do the other directors have to pay?

Comment: Well so far we have been told its only one helper at a time. But I guess I would cross that road when it comes to it. As for why do all directors have to pay the helper, its something they signed into. So your really sure they use the heck out of the helper, and the helper has no free time.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, this just a "simple" join, where you are using overlapping time intervals.  The second part is measuring the period when the helper overlaps with the directors time.  This period starts at the later of the director and helper TimeIn and ends at the earlier of their TimeOut.

I think the following query captures this logic:

```
select d.name as DirectorName, h.name as HelperName,
       (case when d.timeIn > h.timeIn then d.timeIn else h.timeIn end) as HelperStart,
       (case when d.timeOut > h.timeOut then h.timeOut else d.timeOut end) as HelperEnd
from director d join
     helper h
     on d.timeIn < h.timeOut and
        d.timeOut >= h.timeIn
```